# Whats the best setup for a secure remote development environment using Ubuntu VMs in AWS?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, atom-editor, remote-server, nuclide-editor

I have an application which from the business the source code needs to be fully secure.

I am looking at setting up for our devs a remote development environment where they work on their own AWS EC2 VM through secure remote development platform like ATOM Nuclide and commit code via private git or AWS Code Commit.

I was looking at AWS Cloud9 which is a full cloud / web IDE or Using Nuclide to allow remote dev from a client PC.

The constraints are i need our devs to be able to work on the source code (angular 5 + laravel) but not be able to take a copy, down load, copy / paste or take it from the VM which means i need a secure git server too.

It's a business requirement for a large scale valuable platform - no choice.

Comment: Presumably, they can see the source code?  How will you stop them from photographing it?

Comment: Not much we can do with that. if the above requirements can be met then its perfect.

Comment: The best solution is to work with developers you trust and make sure they sign appropriate paperwork.

Comment: I used to work in FB and they had the same set up. above.

Using Nuclice to remote onto your own private VM so all the dev was done remotely.

I am looking for a similar setup.

I appreciate your answer but its  new team and such and told to implement something like this.
.